# Tipos incompatíveis?

Tags: c, array, tipagem

Estou passando 3 parâmetros: um vetor com o nome de 30 cidades, um com as coordenadas x das respectivas cidades e o outro com as coordenadas y.

Preciso imprimir na tela as cidades mais ao norte, sul, etc. Ainda estou fazendo testes. Estou tentando atribuir o valor da cidade para a variável `char cidade` que eu criei (ela só tem 3 índices porque vai ser usada no desempate).
Porém, eu estou tendo um erro:

> "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[150]’ from type ‘char *’" e queria saber qual é o problema.

```
void funcao(char cidadeXY[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[])
{
    int i;

    struct
    {
        int norte, sul, leste, oeste, centro;
        char cidade[150];
    }d[30];

    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++);
    {
        d[i].cidade = cidadeXY[i];
        printf("%s\n", d[i].cidade);
    }
}
```

Como pediram, as declarações e a chamada da função:

```
char cidadeXY[30][150];
void funcao(char cidade[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[])
funcao(cidadeXY, coordenadasX, coordenadasY);
```

O código é beeeem grande e muita coisa dele não tem nada a ver com essa função, por isso só botei as declarações e a chamada.

Comment: A assinatura da função deveria ser: `void funcao(char**  cidadeXY, int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[])`. Se isto resolver me avise que eu adiciono uma resposta oficial.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Só com este trecho pode não estar indicando bem onde está o problema. O problema pode estar na chamada da função, pode ser na declaração desse *array*. Não dá para saber só com as informações fornecidas principalmente onde o erro ocorre.

Esse *array* multidimensional (`cidadeXY`) talvez não faça o que você espera.

O `for` tinha um `;` encerrando ele antes de executar qualquer *loop*. Pode ser que o problema seja só este. Afinal o `i` usado na única interação que seria realizada estaria valendo um valor indefinido.

Não sei se vai fazer mais alguma coisa mas esse código todo não faz muito sentido. Essa `struct` e a própria variável `d` não está servindo para nada. Divida e conquiste. Resolva um problema de cada vez. Por isto retirei a parte que não faz nada útil também. Depois se tudo estiver certo e isto for necessário para alguma coisa você adiciona.

```
void funcao(char cidadeXY[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) printf("%s\n", cidadeXY[i]);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/For.c).

Comment: A chamada da função é: funcao(cidadeXY, coordenadasX, coordenadasY); e a declaração: void funcao(char cidadeXY[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[]); Valeu por apontar o ; depois do for. Não tinha percebido.

Comment: ah e esse código não está funcionando também

Comment: Mas como está a declaração da variável `cidadeXY`? Certamente não está funcionando, existem outros problemas. Edite sua pergunta e coloque outras partes do código.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente como disse o Maniero existe um ";" no que mata seu for. Todo o código é executado uma única vez independentemente da validação do for.

```
for(i = 0; i < 30; i++); <---- Esse ponto e virgula aqui!
{
    d[i].cidade = cidadeXY[i];
    printf("%s\n", d[i].cidade);
}
```

Com esse `;` o *for* não executa nada, e o trecho que deveria estar dentro do for é executado independente do dele uma vez. Como se seu código fosse assim:

```
for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    ;
}

// Isso aqui é executado independente do for
{
    d[i].cidade = cidadeXY[i];
    printf("%s\n", d[i].cidade);
}
```

Para saber mais sobre isso veja esse link  Procure por ["Nested Block Scope"](http://aelinik.free.fr/c/ch14.htm)

Além disso para manipular *strings*, no trecho:

```
d[i].cidade = cidadeXY[i];
```

Você só aponta `d[i].cidade` para a *string* que quer. Isso pode trazer comportamentos inesperados ao seu programa. Se quiser realmente copiar o conteúdo deve fazer o que pmg recomendou:

```
strcpy(d[i].cidade,cidadeXY[i]);
```

Que acredito eu seja o mais recomendado.

Dessa forma seu código ficaria assim:

```
void funcao(char cidadeXY[][150], int coordenadasX[], int coordenadasY[]) {
    int i;
    struct {
        int norte, sul, leste, oeste, centro;
        char cidade[150];
    } d[30];

    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        strcpy(d[i].cidade,cidadeXY[i]);
        printf("%s\n", d[i].cidade);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu já tinha consertado o loop for. Muito obrigada! Eu esqueci totalmente desse função strcpy!

Answer (score 0):

Para atribuir valores a arrays de caracteres (a strings) deves usar `strcpy()`.

```
#include <string.h>

...

        // d[i].cidade = cidadeXY[i];
        strcpy(d[i].cidade, cidadeXY[i]);
```